# How do i pass named parameters (not all string values) to another job in Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to pass a bunch of parameters that are named, some of which are also Maps of named parameters into another job. The below does not work:

```
node
{
    stage ('Deploying')
    {
        build job: 'job-runner', 
        serverSetup: [test: 'test'],
        jobs: [
            myJob: "true"
        ],
        runType: [test: "test"]
    }
}
```

I want the called job to be able to do all of the following:

```
parameters.serverSetup.test
if ( parameters.jobs.MyJob == true )
parameters.runtype.test
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

With the build job function, you can pass parameters. Ex : `build job: 'job-runner', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'string1', value: param1], [$class: 'BooleanParameterValue', name: 'myJob', value: params.myJob]]`

Comment: Right, but how do I pass and array of named parameters as one of the params? For example, I want "myJob" to be its own named parameter list so in the called pipeline I could do: `parameters.myJob.something`

Comment: Ok. sry I don't know.